# Bash - How to output two commands to file?

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to output two commands to a file. I want the exact time (date) AND temperature (sensors) to go to file every 5 minutes. I know how to output one command to a file, but two? How to write such script?

Comment: Please clarify if you are asking to put the output of a command into two files, or if you are asking to put the output of two commands into a file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this?  (In a loop, cron, or whatever you're currently using.)

```
(date; my_sensor_command) >> log_file
```

Comment: +1 for figuring out what the question was...

Comment: +1 simple and easy, output of x commands to one > file

Answer (score 9):

Group all commands in parenthesis, because that will execute them in a sub-shell which you easily can redirect the output from:

```
 while sleep 5m
 do
         (date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M | tr -d '\012'; echo -n ' '; \
         /etc/rc.d/init.d/lm_sensors status | grep '^CPU Temp') >> /your/log/file

 done
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question right--you want to output two values to the same file--then this might be what you are looking for:

```
TIME="`date`"
SENSOR="56"

echo "$TIME $SENSOR" >> /path/to/a/file
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but it looks like all the answers are appending to one file.  I read your question to be that you want the same output in 2 files. If that was what you are looking for, tee is a way to accomplish that:

> echo "Stuff to output"|tee -a file1 file2

Answer (score 1):

Refering to hlovdal post, you can set a cron like this:

```
$ crontab -e
```

*/5 * * * * (echo `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` | tr -d '\012'; echo -n ' ';  sensors | grep "CPU Temp:" | awk '{ print $3 }' )>> /var/log/sensors.log

Comment: Using both grep and awk is very often not neccessary. "grep "CPU Temp:" | awk '{ print $3 }'" can be shortened to "awk '/CPU Temp:/{ print $3 }'"

Answer (score 0):

I know it's and old post but i needed to output the result of over 10 commands to a file, to work with this file and with [@retracile](https://serverfault.com/a/54001/956923) answer i done this (simple & easy):

```
#!/bin/bash

(
command1
command2
command3
MORE COMMANDS
) > OUTPUT_FILE

cat OUTPUT_FILE

# WORK WITH OUTPUT_FILE
...
```

Comment: Note that you can simplify `command > OUTPUT_FILE ; cat OUTPUT_FILE` by using `command | tee OUTPUT_FILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the date and value on the same line:

```
sepChar='_'  #Separator character, for later processing
echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d %H%M%S')$sepChar$(mySensorCmd)" >> outputFile.log
```